# get the data selected from Jquery dialog to the parent page

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've used JQuery dialog to open a popup which contains image

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
  jQuery(document).ready( function(){       
    jQuery("#btnAddWidget").click( showDialog );

      $myWindow = jQuery('#widgetDialog');

      $myWindow.dialog({ height: 350,
        width: 400,
        modal: true,
        position: 'center',
        autoOpen:false,
        title:'Add Widget',
        overlay: { opacity: 0.5, background: 'black'}
      });
    }
  );

  var showDialog = function() {
    $myWindow.show(); 
    $myWindow.dialog("open");
  }

  var closeDialog = function() {
    $myWindow.dialog("close");
  }
</script>
```

In the dialog

```
<div class="headerlinks">
    <input id="btnAddWidget" name="addWidget" value="Add Widget" type="button" />
    <div id="widgetDialog" style="display:none">    
        <img border="0" id="imgRMS" src="sample.jpg" />
        <input id="btnAddToDashboard" name="addToDashboard" value="Add To Dashboard" type="button" />       
    </div>      
</div>
```

In the parent page

```
<div id="dashboard" class="dashboard">
  <div id="w1" class="column"></div>    
</div>
```

On click of "Add to Dashboard" I want the image to be placed in the respective div `w1` of the parent page.
Can anyone suggest something on this..???

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$("#btnAddToDashboard").click(function(e){
    $("#w1").append($("<img>").attr("src",$(this).prev().attr("src")));
});
```

**[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sgr5W/)**

Comment: thanks for the response but can suggest me how can get the whole div to the parent if my image is in another div(in the dialog)